# Setting values of attributes in asciidoctor during Spring's MockMvc building

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Test suite(Spring REST Docs) and I'm wondering is there a way to set values of attributes in the  asciidoctor adoc file during building the MockMvc with MockMvcBuilders ?

For example I have in index.adoc

:myAttribute:

and want to dynamically set it during MockMvc building ?

:myAttribute: myValue

I see in the asciidoctor documentation:

> By default, the attribute assignment precedence, from highest to
>   lowest, is as follows:
>
> ```
> Attribute passed to the API or CLI
>
> Attribute defined in the document
>
> Default value
> ```

And I wonder how to pass it to the API :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of that you could do this. In both cases you'd write the attribute key-value pairs out into a file when you run your tests. You then need to get them into Asciidoctor.

One way to get them into Asciidoctor would be to update your build configuration to read in the file and then set the attributes. I suspect this will only be possible if you're using Gradle. You could write a little bit of Groovy to read in the key-value pairs and add them to the `attributes` map of the `asciidoctor` task.

Another way would be to write an AsciidoctorJ extension that reads in the file containing the key-value pairs and sets the attributes. This approach would work with Maven or Gradle. There's an [example](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctorj/#preprocessor) in the documentation that shows how to use a `Preprocessor` to set an attribute.

Comment: Hello Andy, and thank you for the answer. I will accept it as a correct although I gave up using this approach. It turns out I will have different maven POMs per deployment and I can easily set the attribute thru "asciidoctor-maven-plugin" using the  '<attributes><nameOfAttrInAdoc>Value of the attr</nameOfAttrInAdoc></attributes>' tags, so it wont be much of a hassle. :-)